# Installing Dependencies for Building Unity 8

Tags: dependencies, unity8

If somebody could please tell what I can do to fix this that would be great, because I've tried clearing the build by deleting the cache file and many other desperate attempts. I've searched for every possible solution I could, but I couldn't figure this out. I'm also not sure exactly what this means either. I followed this: https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/

When I got to installing dependencies, I got up to `./build.sh –setup` then got the following output:

```
-- Could NOT find Lcov (missing:  LCOV_EXECUTABLE GENHTML_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find gcovr (missing:  GCOVR_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core"
  (requested version 5.2) with any of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nathanzm/unity8/trunk/builddir/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably did the same mistake as me and copied the command from the wiki page.

Type the command manually `./build.sh --setup`. That worked for me. You will have to do a clean build afterwards.

`./build.sh -c`

Comment: Thanks, I actually followed the directions on the official ubuntu page, but I'll have to give this one a try!

Answer (score -1):

The "Building Unity 8" guide is outdated.

To get started, install **Ubuntu 15.10** and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y bzr unity8
sudo apt-get build-dep -y unity8

mkdir -p ~/unity8

bzr branch lp:unity8 ~/unity8/trunk

cd ~/unity8/trunk
./build.sh --setup
./build.sh
./run.sh
```